# Connecting multiple LED strips in parallel to a 220v/5A power line (via 12V driver)

Tags: led, current, parallel, circuit-protection

I would like to power 5 LED strips via a 220v/5A wall outlet (each strip is 5m in length). I will be consulting and employing the electrician for the best way to run the wiring but from the initial phone call, he said he isn't too knowledgeable about LED strips and said he would bring along a fellow professional. Until that happens, I'm hoping I can get a better understanding on this topic from the folks on this group.

The reason I would like to run all 5 strips from the same socket is so I can power them all using a single switch that already happens to be in the wall switch board. Please note that I will be using a 12V/5A driver at the head of each strip.

My concern is whether powering all 5 strips from one socket is even possible. When I look at the LED specs, it says the power consumption is 72W for 5m which I take means a current draw of 6A. WOuldn't that mean just one strip would max out a 5A mains supply line or am I wrong in my calculations?

If indeed each strip requires one 5A line, does this mean I will need to power each strip from a different wall socket (or 5A line)? AFAIK a 5A line is good for 1100W (220vx5A) but as I've described, that contradicts the 'amperage view' if I can call it that. I'm pretty sure I'm messing up something here, just hoping you knowledgeable folks can help me sort my confusion.

My end goal is to have all 5 strips controlled by a single wall switch. If there's a better way to go about this, please share your thoughts.

While we're on this subject, I would also like to run some safety fuse into each LED strip. What's a good way to do it? get a 7A fuse? Would appreciate pointers to any products or links that explain adding the fuses.

Comment: Since the LEDs are not powered directly from the mains, instead a AC-DC converter module sits between, you estimate the total power at 5 stripes * (12v * 5A) = 5 * 60 = 300 watts. This requires about 1.2 amps from the wall.

Comment: The primary job of a fuse would be to protect the cable to the LED strip from overheating if too much current passed through it. As your driver is unlikely to be able to supply enough current to cause that to happen there's not much point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I look at the LED specs, it says the power consumption is 72W for 5m which I take means a current draw of 6A.

You say each strip will use 72W so 12V 6A.

Switching 12V DC power supply usually have an efficiency in the 80-90% range, so for a 72W output it will draw between 80W and 90W on 230 VAC, which corresponds to 0.4A max per 72W strip.

That's 2A for five strips, so you can use your 230V 5A outlet, no problem.

You can use a 12V 6A (or more) supply per strip, or a 12V 30A (or more) supply for all strips.

Note that 72W*5 gives about 28000 lumens, which is enormous.

Comment: Ah this is what I was missing - since there is a step down transformer involved, the current the LED strip receives is higher than the incoming transformer current (i.e. mains current). Thanks!